Remove "Live Activity controls" from iOS lock screen (such as audio controls for BBC iPlayer, Apple Music, Spotify, etc)
How can this control be removed?

The app in question is BBC Sounds, but these controls also appear with Apple Music, Spotify and likely any other audio app.
The trouble is, these controls are permanently on the lock screen, evidently even when the phone is in my pocket. On numerous occasions now, I've gone to get something else out of the same pocket, touched the screen and ended up jumping to a totally different point of the show I'm listening too. Of course, as the phone is in my pocket, I can't see where I was to skip back to it, which is pretty infuriating...
I've tried:

Settings -> Face ID & Passcode -> Allow access when locked and turning everything off: The audio controls are still present

Settings -> Notifications: there is no section for BBC Sounds, turning off for Apple Music made no difference

In the BBC Sounds app itself, there's nothing it settings that would prevent this. Apple Music and Spotify do not appear to have settings sections within their apps.

I'm on the latest iOS version, currently 17.5.1

I've tried removing widgets using this guide and this guide, but I don't think this is actually a widget.


I've asked this over in Apple Community too.

I contacted Apple Support, went through the tedious first-level escalation process, and eventually got someone who acknowledged the issue and that there is basically no way to turn this off at the moment.
The best they could offer was to complain through Apple's Product Feedback, so I've sent a "Bug Report" through the iPhone Feedback channel and would suggest anyone impacted by this to do the same, here are the comments I used:
It is currently impossible to disable the cross-app player controls on the lock screen. 

These controls are permanently on the lock screen, evidently even when the phone is in my pocket. 
On numerous occasions now, I've gone to get something else out of the same pocket, touched the screen and ended up jumping to a totally different point of the show I'm listening too. 

Please see details here:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/472851/remove-audio-controls-from-ios-lock-screen-bbc-iplayer-apple-music-spotify-e

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/255621763?sortBy=best


A possible workaround suggested by BBC Sounds for this issue would be to disable the "Rise to Wake" feature on your device as this may prevent you screen waking when your phone is within your pocket. You can find help on how to do this here.
